# Tails 3.0 blocks connection to ANY obfs4 bridge

Tags: tails, bridge, obfs4

I've attempted to use six different obfs4 bridge relays and according to the tor log the connection is terminated. using obfs3 does work. any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your time zone and time settings are correct, if your system clock time is off, obfs4 will fail to connect.

Tails automatically synchronize time upon start, but sometimes the time synchronization may fail(the OS notify you when that happens). I'm not sure which timezone you're in, however, as a last resort, if you own the computer you're using and it has another operating system, try to log onto it, first make sure your computer's local time is correct, then change your computer's timezone to 'UTC' that is universal coordinated time, restart your computer and boot from tails.  obfs4 bridges will now work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The current timesync mechanism in Tails with Bridges is also fragile, if the time is askew on either client on bridge a little bit, it can cause some problems (you'll notice your time jump back while connecting...). Sometimes it will take a few tries to connect (Requires a reboot).

Answer (score 1):

Set the time zone to London and change time to London time. You can update the time first when you connect to the wireless internet (not yet configuring tor), once that is done you can connect without any problem. If there are problems, try -1 hour or +1 hour to account for daylight savings depending on your area. Mine was -1 and worked well.

You can also edit the `iat-mode=0` to `iat-mode=1` or `iat-mode=2`.

Good luck.

Comment: A) It should be UTC, not London (London shifts +1 for BST) and B) Editing `iat-mode` isn't a good idea, you should keep what the bridge line provides (since it won't help if the client changes it to a higher setting, the server will still keep whatever `iat-mode` it is configured with)